# Ignore class functions / methods during XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

How do you ignore a function / method of a class so that you can serialize it to disk for later use?

I have searched and really cant find any answers.  I need the ToString()because I add each instance of the Person to a list box.  The ToString() is what is displayed in the list box.  I then use the selected items to get it back again to work with the object.

x = (Person)listbox selected items.

If I try t serialize it as below it blow up.

```
public class Person
{    
    public Person()
    {
        messages = new List<Message>();
    }

    public string name{ get; set;}        
    public List<Message> messages{ get; set;}        

// How do you ignore this????
// [XMLIgnore] does not work
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Here is the call to serialize it.  It blows up when I try to create the XmlSearlizer object.

Other classes that have no methods / functions work fine.  No problems.

```
public void serializeToXML<T>(T test)
{
    // If object has method or function it blows up here.
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
    // Hardcoded just for a test.
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml"); 
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, test);
    textWriter.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  There must be something else going on.  What's the exact exception you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToString()` has no effect on `XmlSerializer`.  `XmlSerializer` serializes public properties and fields only.  Not methods.

I ran your sample code replacing `Message` with `string` and it serialized fine in .NET 3.5.  There's something in your `Message` class, which you didn't include, that is causing whatever error you're seeing.

Comment: I was getting a Person Reflection error.  The issue was with the Message object.  I didn't have a default constructor that took 0 parameters.  The message was so vague that I didn't realize that the actual underlying error was at message and not with person.  Sometimes I tell you.  Thank you again for all your help and it pointed me to look a little deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the ToString() method? Why can't you just use your 'name' property?

Comment: I was using the ToString in order to use that value to display in list-boxes as I assigned each object to an Item in the control.  ToString displays automatically.